# Kendo UI custom autocomplete editor for foreign key grid column

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

This is the scenario: i want to implement custom autocomplete editor for a foreign key column grid using Kendo UI.

This is the solution: for the foreign key grid column i use default kendo mechanism so the column display the value instead of id.

This is the problem: for that column i use a custom autocomplete editor but:

- when i click into the autocomplete widget it displays the id not the value
- when i save a new value autocomplete widget does not show the value

The code below show detail grid initialization (master grid not shown). Column

> group_id

is the foreign key. Variable

> groups

contains the key value list used to display group name instead of id.

> getGroupsAsync(e)

is the function the read from the specified data source the list of all available groups.

```
//function used to async load groups
var getGruppiAsync = function (e) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred(),
        loadGruppi = function () {
            new kendo.data.DataSource({
                type: "odata",
                serverPaging: false,
                transport: {
                    read: "/Services/MusicStore.svc/GetGroupsByUser?id_utente=guid'" + e.data.id_utente + "'"
                },
                schema: {
                    data: function (data) {
                        return data.d.results;
                    },
                    total: function (data) {
                        return data.d.results.length;
                    }
                }
            }).fetch(function (data) {
                deferred.resolve($.map(data.items, function (item) {
                    return {
                        value: item.id_gruppo,
                        text: item.nome
                    };
                }));
            });
        };

    window.setTimeout(loadGruppi, 1);
    return deferred.promise();
}; 

$.when(getGroupsAsync(e)).done(function (groups) {
        $("<div id='group-grid'/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
            toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"],
            editable: "incell",
            autoBind: true,
            dataSource: {
                type: "odata",
                serverFiltering: true,
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "/Services/MusicStore.svc/Gruppi_Utenti"
                    },
                    create: {
                        url: function () {
                            return "/Services/MusicStore.svc/Gruppi_Utenti"
                        },
                        type: "POST",
                        data: function (data) {
                            data.utente_id = e.data.id_utente;
                            data.id_gruppi_utente = Math.uuid();
                            data.gruppo_id = selectedGruppo;
                            if (data.id_gruppo)
                                delete data["id_gruppo"];
                        },
                    },
                    update: {
                        url: function (data) {
                            return "/Services/MusicStore.svc/Gruppi_Utenti(guid'" + data.id_gruppi_utente + "')";
                        },
                        type: "PUT",
                        data: function (data) {
                            data.gruppo_id = selectedGruppo;
                            if (data.id_gruppo)
                                delete data["id_gruppo"];
                        }
                    },
                    destroy: {
                        url: function (data) {
                            return "/Services/MusicStore.svc/Gruppi_Utenti(guid'" + data.id_gruppi_utente + "')";
                        },
                        type: "DELETE"
                    },
                    parameterMap: function (data, type) {
                        if (type == "read") {
                            // call the default OData parameterMap
                            var result = kendo.data.transports.odata.parameterMap(data);

                            if (result.$filter) {
                                // encode everything which looks like a GUID
                                var guid = /('[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}')/ig;
                                result.$filter = result.$filter.replace(guid, "guid$1");
                            }
                            return result;
                        } else return JSON.stringify(data);
                    }

                },
                filter: { field: "utente_id", operator: "eq", value: e.data.id_utente },
                schema: {
                    model: detailModel,
                    total: function (response) {
                        if (response.length == 0) return 0;
                        return response.d.__count;
                    }
                },
                error: showError
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    field: "group:id",
                    title: "Gruppi",
                    editor: detailEditor,
                    values: groups,
                },
                {
                    command: ["destroy"], title: "&nbsp;"
                }
            ]
        });
    });
```

This function provides autocomplete editor for column group_id

```
var gruppiDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    type: "odata",
    serverPaging: false,
    serverFiltering: false,
    transport: {
        read: "/Services/MusicStore.svc/Gruppi",
    },
    schema: {
        data: function (data) {
            return data.d.results;
        },
        total: function (data) {
            return data.d.results.length;
        }
    }

});

gruppiDataSource.read();

function detailEditor(container, options) {
    //$('<input data-text-field="nome" data-text-value="nome" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
    $('<input data-text-field="nome" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
                    .appendTo(container)
                    .kendoAutoComplete({
                        //index: 0,
                        highlightFirst: true,
                        autoBind: false,
                        placeholder: "Select group",
                        dataTextField: "nome",
                        //dataValueField: "id_gruppo",
                        filter: "contains",
                        minLength: 3,
                        select: onGroupSelect,
                        change: function(e){

                        },
                        dataSource: gruppiDataSource
                    });
}
```

The problem with this code is that when i enter in editing mode autocomplete widget show the id of the group instead of name and when i save data the widget remain blank.

The data is sent to server but i can't get the gui elements with the correct values.

Some suggestions?

Comment: Did you ever get this working?